# What is an "adadadadadadadadadad"?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've heard this term repeatedly used in context of strafing as well as landing shots.  What does it mean in terms of Counter Strike, and why is it so controversial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research on this matter because i was very curious about it when you posted this question and i finally found what adada is.

ADADADADA is pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> keys to strafe left and right while you're shooting. It makes you harder to hit (since you're moving left and right constantly enemies will miss you more often then they would if you were standing still), but strafing left and right doesn't really reduce your accuracy by much, it's almost the same as if you were shooting while standing still.

That taken into account, a lot of people are saying ADADA is abuse since you're just as accurate and you're harder to hit.

Comment: " strafing left and right doesn't really reduce your accuracy by much, it's almost the same as if you were shooting while standing still." ... Uh, that's really not true.

Comment: From what I hear it seems to be a problem a lot of players are fed up with in CS:GO, but I'm not too into the competitive scene so I don't know what's all the ruckus about

Comment: @Decency From what Iv'e read and saw in youtube videos it is. Even people using snipers do it, they strafe left and right and then shoot and they hit almost every single time which means accuracy is not really compromised, and they're harder to hit. That's why everyone is complaining about ADADADA spammers.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ The way to do this skillfully is to tap the opposite directional key as your're strafing in time with your shots so that you stop your aim on a dime. If you don't do that, your shots are much more random. With some guns, specifically the P90 and other SMG's, the difference isn't much, but with any of the top rifles in the game it's a huge difference.

Comment: *"strafing left and right doesn't really reduce your accuracy by much"* is false.  However, as soon as you let go of the strafe key, your accuracy begins to rapidly increase.  If you shoot shortly after letting go of the key, you'll have full accuracy.  It was the same in CS 1.6 and CS:S.  It's much easier to see with 'auto' crosshair enabled, but I don't think CS:GO has that.